# Calculation of landing page in bigquey

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

i want to know the number of purchase and new users of my landing page in bigquey.
i write this query but it does not work :

```
select
case when
(select value.int_value from unnest (event_params) where key = "entrances") = 1 then (select value.string_value from unnest (event_params) where key = "page_location") end as landing_page ,

countif (event_name = "first_visit") as new_users
from `my-websire-ga4.analytics_345406046.events_*`
group by landing_page
having landing_page is not null
order by new_users desc ;
```

the column of new_users is 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the "entrances" parameter isn't sent with the first visit event, you can use this query instead :

```js
select
(select value.string_value from unnest (event_params) where key = "page_location") as landing_page , countif (event_name = "first_visit") as new_users from your_dataset group by landing_page having landing_page is not null order by new_users desc ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to count the user id field for the new user metric, as there are potentially many events triggered by a user's session.  The following gets you what you are looking for by using `ga_session_number`:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ( SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST (event_params) WHERE KEY = "entrances") = 1 THEN ( SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST (event_params) WHERE KEY = "page_location")
END
  AS landing_page,
  CASE WHEN( SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST (event_params) WHERE KEY = "ga_session_number") = 1 THEN 'new'
  ELSE
  'return'
END
  AS user_type,
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) AS user_count
FROM
  `my-websire-ga4.analytics_345406046.events_*`
GROUP BY
  landing_page,
  user_type
HAVING
  landing_page IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  user_count DESC ;
```